# Django Rest Framework resource doesn't respond to request with invalid token

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have Django project with ViewSet model inherited from Django Rest Framework `models.GenericViewSet`

At the top of the ViewSet I've set up authentication with
`permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`

When I make a request with an existing token, it works as expected. But if the token doesn't exist, the server seems to never respond.

How can I debug this behavior? Or probably do I need something else for this permission class to properly process invalid tokens?

I need the server to respond with something about wrong credentials. For example, 401 and some custom message (if there is no better alternative).

Comment: The server gets stuck? No request logs are found?

Comment: I didn't manage to find log records related to requests with invalid token. And found logs for successful requests.

Comment: Does it do this with Django's `runserver`? If so, you should be able to put a breakpoint or use `ipython`'s `embed()` function to get a CLI inside the view to see what's going on.

Comment: Can you add the relevant portions of your code such as `views.py`, `models.py` etc ?

Comment: Which authentication classes are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put this code inside your view?

```
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
```